# Move Drop down Arrow to Right of Link Element

Tags: html, css

I have the arrow for the drop down under the First_Name, Last_Name. I want to move this to the right side of it. The arrow signifies that this particular link is a drop down. I want to move this drop down arrow to the right side of the logged in users name. (First Name, Last Name) values will be dynamic, depending on the user that is logged in. I have tried a few things, one of which is:

HTML:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
        <!--Not sure about path of [routerLink]="['/login']" **make sure to check** -->
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" [routerLink]="['/login']" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded="false">
          {{userName}}
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <!--
              <a class="dropdown-item text-uppercase" href="">Profile</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item text-uppercase" href="">Settings</a>
          -->
          <a class="dropdown-item">Logout</a>
        </div>
      </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-toggle-ellipsis::after { display: none; } 
.dropdown-toggle::after { display: none; }
```

But this didnt work, out. Any suggestions? I am new to this, so sorry if this question is basic. Thanks for all the help!!

This image shows the LastName, FirstName Link in my navbar, and the arrow underneath:

[image]

Comment: so you want the log out to be next to the username, like adjacent side?

Comment: no i want the drop down arrow, which is located under the element currently, to go on the right side of the "First_Name"

Answer (score 0):

If you want the dropdown to be adjacent to the username you need to use a span tag instead of the div tag. The span tag creates an inline block and the content written inside it stays in the same line. Replace your HTML with this.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
        <!--Not sure about path of [routerLink]="['/login']" **make sure to check** -->
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" [routerLink]="['/login']" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded="false">
          {{userName}}
        </a>
        <span class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <!--
              <a class="dropdown-item text-uppercase" href="">Profile</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item text-uppercase" href="">Settings</a>
          -->
        <a class="dropdown-item">Logout</a>
        </span>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Hope I understood your question right and hope this helps. Please give a thumbs up if this works.

Comment: No, not exactly. The dropdown arrow is currently underneath the element, i want to place that to the right of "FirstName".

Comment: I don't see the first name when I tried to create a fiddle of your problem.I am guessing your data is abstracted away. I could see something called username though and my codeputs the button to the right of that.